# Adjust alignment of entire table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the following two tables in my document; table 2 is properly aligned, but table 3 is overfull, so hangs over on the right. Any suggestions on how to get it to centre properly on the page without splitting the numerical values in the table over multiple lines?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l||r|r|r|r|r|}

\hline

Region & \textit{A} (cloud fraction) &\(\omega\) (rad/h)&\(\phi\) (rad)&\(\Bar{y}\) (cloud fraction) & NRMSE\\
\hline
\hline
Trop. Sea & 0.0112 ± 0.00127 & 0.526 ± 0.109&-0.328 ± 1.37& 0.15 ± 0.00129 & 0.0142\\
\hline
Trop. Land   & 0.0283 ± 0.00486 & 0.581 ± 0.101 &-1.77 ± 1.24&0.0544 ± 0.00472 & 0.0794\\
\hline
Non-trop. Sea  & 43.0 ± 2.14e+05 &-0.00549 ± 13.7& -4.64 ± 180& -42.9 ± 2.14 & 0.173\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Fitted values after least squares optimisation}
\label{tab:init_vals}

\end{table}
```

[image: Table 2 is properly aligned, Table 3 is overfull, so is asymmetrically aligned]

Comment: Welcome. Maybe put the units in an aditional line and add a multiplicator for the values like `(11.2 +- 1.27)*e-03` for [1,1].

Comment: An other option would be to decrease the font size

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The second table seems too wide to fit between margins. I'd suggest redesigning tables – swapping rows and columns  (and using the `S` column type from `siunitx`).

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. How to make a table fit into the available space depend on how much space there is.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options/332903#332903) for more ideas on how to resize the table so it fits in the margins.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compilable and even if it was there is nothing to produce your table 2. As @Bernard suggested the best bet is to swap the rows and columns. However, if you insist on your table layout then you could use the `changepage` package to make extra horizontal space for your table.

```
% widefloatprob.tex SE 589062

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l||r|r|r|r|r|}

\hline

Region & \textit{A} (cloud fraction) &\(\omega\) (rad/h)&\(\phi\) (rad)&\(\Bar{y}\) (cloud fraction) & NRMSE\\
\hline
\hline
Trop. Sea & 0.0112 ± 0.00127 & 0.526 ± 0.109&-0.328 ± 1.37& 0.15 ± 0.00129 & 0.0142\\
\hline
Trop. Land   & 0.0283 ± 0.00486 & 0.581 ± 0.101 &-1.77 ± 1.24&0.0544 ± 0.00472 & 0.0794\\
\hline
Non-trop. Sea  & 43.0 ± 2.14e+05 &-0.00549 ± 13.7& -4.64 ± 180& -42.9 ± 2.14 & 0.173\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Fitted values after least squares optimisation}
\label{tab:init_vals}

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]